# Button Submits Although It is Not a Submit Button

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want the submit button first validate the form using a JavaScript script but it does not. It directly calls action in controller. So I changed it to a button so it is not a submit button anymore but weirdly it still submits the form. I added onclick as an attribute but it does not fire the function.

Code simply looks as below; I tried onclick="return validateForm()" as well.

```
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="popup('@Url.Action("NewStudentSchedule", "Admin", newStudent)','New Student Schedule')" value="Schedule" /></td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(s => @Model[i].Teacher, new SelectList(teacherList), "Select Teacher", new { @class = "btn btn-light  dropdown-toggle", id = "selectTeacher" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => @Model[i].StartingDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", id = "startDate" })</td>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => @Model[i].IsNowStudent, new { @id = "isNowStudent" })</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="validateForm();">Save</button></td>
```

JavaScript Function is as below. I put breakpoints to see if compiler ever visits it, but nothing.

```js
 function validateForm() {
 
 // Validation Code
 
 }
```

Action in controller;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentApplicants(List<StudentApplicant> studentApplicant)
{
    TempData.Keep();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value of `type` attribute in `button` element is `submit`.

`validateForm()` button should have attribute `type="button"`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="validateForm();">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added type to the button but now nothing happens. It still doesn't fire the function validateForm() and also it does not jump into the action in controller. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

`<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="validateForm();">`

Should be
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="validateForm();">`

The default [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) for the html button is `submit`.

For your code in `validateForm()`, you can confirm that it works by doing something like this

```
function validateForm() {
 
 // Validation Code
 console.log("Hi, This Works!")
 }
```